# How to draw a line within a view along the frame?

Tags: android, animation, timeline, dialogfragment, waze

I'm trying to create a dialog fragment whose frame has a line that gets smaller (like a snake) at a certain time, of course in animation.
It's like in Waze application, only that the line is complete and small at first.
Pay attention to the increasing line size of the "go now" button in the Gif

[image]

1. how achieve line that gets smaller?
2. how achieve the Waze animation, increasing line size?

Comment: https://github.com/AbhinavChauhan97/LoaderChip

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution and built a library, you can see the tutorial how to use it [here](https://medium.com/@bagiyoni/draw-a-path-with-animation-b97a35ba03e6)

Simple implementation with Gradle dependency

> implementation ‘com.bagi: drawerpath: 1.4’